# Writing struct + saving only pointer?

Tags: c

I am allocating space for the struct node in the variable n0. I save this struct to file using fwrite, but many people say that I'm only saving the pointer to the ustr. But I need save the string ustr, Could you help please?

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char * ustr;
    int height;
}node;

void node_init(node * n, int r) {

    int i;
    n->ustr = malloc((r + 1) * sizeof(unsigned char));
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        (n->ustr)[i] = random() & 0xff;
    }
    (n->ustr)[r] = 0;
    n->height = -1;
}
void node_destroy(node * n) {
    free(n->ustr);
    n->height = -1;
}

int main() {
    FILE* file_ptr = fopen("file1", "w+");
    node n0;
    node_init(&n0,2);
    fwrite(&n0, sizeof(node), 1, file_ptr);
    fclose(file_ptr);
    node_destroy(&n0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Absolutelu `(n->ustr)[i]`, no need for parentheses.

Comment: Yes, the important thing is that `sizeof(node)` is not enough. And your code can very easily cause undefined behavior.

Comment: add length of `ustr` member to `node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(node)` is wrong, because it's using the size of `int` and the size of the `pointer`, not the size of the `string`. You would have to either allocate a `string` as e.g. `unsigned char ustr[10]` or dynamically allocate the string but use the characters you allocted to find the size and provide the string's pointer to `fwrite`.

If you statically allocate the string, this should work:

```
fwrite(&n0, sizeof(node), 1, file_ptr);
```

Otherwise, if you dynamically allocate the string, you should do:

```
fwrite(&(n0 + sizeof(unsigned char *)), sizeof(int), 1, file_ptr);
fwrite(n0.ustr, length_node, 1, file_ptr);
```

or better:

```
fwrite(&n0.height, sizeof(int), 1, file_ptr);
fwrite(n0.ustr, length_node, 1, file_ptr);
```

Comment: if the lenght is defined #define length_node 3, in compile time Can I use that length_node?

Comment: You mean `unsigned char ustr[length_node + 1]` ? Sure. I'm just using `+ 1` for the `null byte`

Comment: it is possbile write making changing fwrite(&n0, sizeof(node), 1, file_ptr); by fwrite(&n0, 2*sizeof(int) + 2*(unsigned char), 1, file_ptr);?

Comment: @Juan I've edite my post to provide 2 cases of `fwrite`

Comment: it is possbile write making changing fwrite(&n0, sizeof(node), 1, file_ptr); by fwrite(&n0, 2*sizeof(int) + 2*(unsigned char), 1, file_ptr);?

Comment: Is the string statically allocated? Then `fwrite(&n0, sizeof(int) + 2*(unsigned char), 1, file_ptr);` (without the `2` in the `sizeof(int)`). OTHERWISE, if it dynamically allocated, neither should work.

Answer (score 1):

I answered this in your other question as well, but basically, just write the two fields separately instead of writing the whole struct at once:

```
int main() {
    const int count = 2;
    FILE* file_ptr = fopen("file1", "w+");
    node n0;
    node_init(&n0,count);
    /* write length of string so reader will know how much to read back */
    fwrite(&count, sizeof(count), 1, file_ptr);
    fwrite(n0.ustr, count, 1, file_ptr);
    fwrite(&n0.height, sizeof(n0.height), 1, file_ptr);
    fclose(file_ptr);
    node_destroy(&n0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strlen` may not function correctly. Because it may contain  `0` to the contents. `(n->ustr)[i] = random() & 0xff;` : `random() & 0xff` might become 0.

Comment: it is possbile write making changing fwrite(&n0, sizeof(node), 1, file_ptr); by fwrite(&n0, 2*sizeof(int) + 2*(unsigned char), 1, file_ptr);?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it is possbile write making changing fwrite(&n0, sizeof(node), 1, file_ptr); by fwrite(&n0, 2*sizeof(int) + 2*(unsigned char), 1, file_ptr);?

Comment: @MarcFraioli In preparation for the reading you need to write out the length.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY well that depends on whether the length is constant or not. He had it hard-coded to 2 in the original example so I left it at that.

Comment: `node_init(node * n, int r)` `r` is not necessarily to be called with `2`. `r` argument not need  If it is fixed.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, I concede.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the number of elements `ustr` is fixed at compile time, make it an array with that number of elements, and don't `malloc()` it.    That ensures the array rather than a pointer is written.

If the length of the string is NOT fixed at compile time (e.g. an integral value that is derived from user input) - and you want to be able to read the struct in again at another time using `fread()`, and get the same data as was written - then you would need to store the length in the struct, and use two calls of `fwrite()` (the first one will need to save the length, and the second will need to output that number of characters).  For example;

```
typedef struct
{
    int height;           /*  note change of order of member */
    int ustr_length;
    unsigned char * ustr;
} node;

void node_init(node * n, int r)
{
    int i;
    n->ustr = malloc((r + 1) * sizeof(unsigned char));
    n->ustr_length = r+1;       /*  save the length of u->str */
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        (n->ustr)[i] = random() & 0xff;
    }
    (n->ustr)[r] = 0;
    n->height = -1;
}
void node_destroy(node * n)
{
    free(n->ustr);
    n->height = -1;
    n->ustr_length = 0;
}

int main()
{
    FILE* file_ptr = fopen("file1", "w+");
    node n0;
    node_init(&n0,2);
    fwrite(&n0.height, 2*sizeof(int), 1, file_ptr);
    fwrite(n0.ustr, n0.ustr_length, 1, file_ptr);
    fclose(file_ptr);
    node_destroy(&n0);
    return 0;
}
```

Translating this into code that can use `fread()` to read the data back in and reconstruct the original struct is trivial.

It is a really good idea to do error checking.  `malloc()`, `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fread()`, etc can all fail, and ignoring that is dangerous.

Comment: `fwrite(&n0.height, 2*sizeof(int), 1, file_ptr);` This is not correct if the padding exist.

Comment: it is possbile write making changing fwrite(&n0, sizeof(node), 1, file_ptr); by fwrite(&n0, 2*sizeof(int) + 2*(unsigned char), 1, file_ptr);?

Comment: `fwrite(&n0.height, 2*sizeof(int), 1, file_ptr);` --> `fwrite(&n0.height, sizeof(int), 1, file_ptr);fwrite(&n0.ustr_length, sizeof(int), 1, file_ptr);`